# Virtocommerce new filter does not appear

Tags: e-commerce, virtocommerce

Virtocommerce has default filter for Brands, Color, etc. 
I need implement a new filter called `IDConcurso`. This field (IDConcurso) is registered like a property of item.
I inserted the code bellow in table StoreSetting to XML column of row named "FilteredBrowsing":

```
<attribute key="IDConcurso" localized="false">
    <simple id="Test1" value="1" />
    <simple id="Test2" value="2" /> 
    <simple id="Test3" value="3" /> 
</attribute>
```

I also added the property called `IDConcurso` in all items. But this filter never appear on the left side. What do I need to do more?
Do I need to change any code for filtering items by property called IDConcurso? Or I need just pass by QueryString `..../?f_idconcurso=1` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filter will only appear if there are product that have those properties. If products do have those properties then you also might need to to rebuild the index.

Simply open Commerce Manager and go to the settings->search and click re-build index button.